# What are the differences between the rsync delete options?

Tags: rsync

I see on the [rsync man page](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) that there are a number of `delete` options, but don't really understand the differences between them.  What are the differences between these options?

```
 --del                   an alias for --delete-during
 --delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
 --delete-before         receiver deletes before transfer (default)
 --delete-during         receiver deletes during xfer, not before
 --delete-delay          find deletions during, delete after
 --delete-after          receiver deletes after transfer, not before
 --delete-excluded       also delete excluded files from dest dirs
```

Comment: Why `--delete-before` is described as `(default)`? I cannot understand what `(default)` means.

Comment: It's no longer specified as default in the `man` page for `rsync version 3.1.2  protocol version 31`. However, my guess on the version with the quoted text is that if you only use `--delete` rather than `--delete-WHEN`, then it's as if you specified `--delete-WHEN` where `WHEN` defaults to `before`.

Comment: See also this relevant question about how to delete *source* files ***after*** transfer: [rsync delete files on sending side after transfer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801243/rsync-delete-files-on-sending-side-after-transfer) ... and see this equally valuable question about how to delete directories as well: [Usage of --remove-source-files option of rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371144/usage-of-remove-source-files-option-of-rsync)

Answer (score 191, accepted):

- `--del/--delete_during`: Deletes files from the destination dir as they are copied (saves memory compared to `--delete-before`: `--delete-before` makes a separate scan to look for deleteables)
- `--delete`: Deletes files in the destination directory if they don't exist in the source directory.
- `--delete-before`: Delete files in the destination directory before copying file-with-same-name from source directory
- `--delete-during`: Delete files in the destination directory WHILE copying file-with-same-name from source directory
- `--delete-delay`: Mark deletes during transfer, but wait until transfer is complete
- `--delete-after`: Receiver deletes after transfer, not before...If some other part of the rsync moved extra files elsewhere, you'd want this instead of `--delete-delay`, because `--delete-delay` decides what it's going to delete in the middle of transfer, whereas `--delete-after` checks the directory for files that should be deleted AFTER everything is finished.
- `--delete-excluded`: Deletes files from the destination directory that are explicitly excluded from transferring from the source directory.

The point of rsync is not copying, it is archiving. This is an important distinction. Processing deleted/changed files is critical, and in many cases nuanced.

The `--delete` flag in particular is one I've seen screwed up many times. A lot of people use rsync to move files to low priority storage, and in this case you want the files you're moving to still EXIST in the destination directory. That's not what delete does: `--delete` makes sure that, when you delete a file from the source directory, it is ALSO deleted from your destination directory, so your destination doesn't get full of junk... Once saw a guy wipe out his backup by putting in a new drive, and not turning off his nightly rsync script. Script saw that the source dir was now empty, and it deleted every file in the destination dir, so they'd match.

Most of the other options are space or performance related. When you delete the files is important if you want to make sure the transfer is successful before you do anything, but if your device is too small to handle 2 copies of all the information, you need to delete as you go, etc. It's a little wacky because of its long history across multiple platforms: some options have been added so that people who were used to certain behaviour wouldn't be confused.

Comment: So is --delete and --delete-before the same? man rsync doesn't say when --delete deletes files.

Comment: @ppr: Depends on the system. The reason it has so many specific options is because delete on Solaris != delete on HP-UX != delete on AIX != delete on Linux.

Comment: When rsyncing a whole directory, does `delete-after` delete each file in between syncing, or only after the whole dir has been mirrored? I thought `delete-after` was sufficient for my needs but i'm getting no space left on device when backup up one of my drives.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat: Delete after won't delete anything until after it's done the transfer.

Comment: By "the transfer" you mean the whole directory structure? Or individual file?

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat: Either. It moves everything it's going to move, and when it's done, it's starts deleting things. If you want it to delete before it's moved everything, use --delete-during

Comment: Got it. In summary to my query, when you're trying to mirror an entire drive that is almost full, you have to use `delete-during` otherwise you'll get a `no space left on device`.

Comment: After some experience, I'm finding that even `delete-during` doesn't always prevent `no space left on device` (on Linux). So `delete-before` is the only guaranteed way to avoid it (like when mirroring a drive that is almost full, and the destination drive is almost full too).

Comment: In Windows terms, using --delete is like adding the /MIR option to Robocopy.  BUT THERE IS A CATCH.  If you change your excludes it will NOT delete the new excluded files from the destination.

Answer (score 51):

By default `rsync` doesn't delete any files at the destination side. To make `rsync` delete files at all, you need to use at least one of the delete options.

If you don't care when files are being deleted, just use `--delete` and leave the choice to `rsync`. You can combine `--delete` with other delete options (this doesn't conflict) but you don't have to as all other delete options already imply `--delete`.

`--delete-before` works as follows: `rsync` looks which files are present at the source and which files are present at the destination, deletes all files found at the destination but not at the source and then starts the actual synchronization. This order is useful if the destination has little storage space as it will first free up more disk space at the destination before starting transferring any new files. The downside is that `rsync` will require more memory to perform the operation and the whole operation is a two step process and thus slower.

`--delete-during` works as follows: `rsync` immediately starts to synchronize files and when it comes across a file that exists only at the destination, it is deleted. That way there is no speed penalty and also no additional memory is required. The downside is that it may happen that first a lot of new files are copied to the destinations before removed files are being deleted, so the destination may require much more disk storage space during the operation than it requires in the end once the entire operation is done.

`--delete-after` works as follows: First synchronize all files, then perform the same operation that `--delete-before` performs before the synchronization phase. This is the worst choice in most common cases as it requires most memory, most disk space at the destination, and it is slower as it is a two step process; basically it combines all disadvantages of the other two methods. This option mainly exists for the case that you are using "*merge files*" (what merge files are and how they work is beyond the scope of this answer). As these files may contain rules for files to be excluded during delete, new merge files must be copied before the deletion phase if their content shall be considered during the deletion phase. Unless that is a requirement, `--delete-after` has no advantage.

`--delete-delay` is a rather new option (it's not available in `rsync` 2.6.9, which is still the default in macOS 10.15 for example). It works like `--delete-during`, except that it won't delete files immediately but after the synchronization is done, so it is a hybrid of `--delete-during` and `--delete-after`. The advantages are that it is faster than `--delete-after` and still supports merge files correctly, the disadvantage is that it requires more memory and disk space during the synchronization just like `--delete-after`.

`--delete-excluded` tells `rsync` to not just delete files that are missing at the source but to also delete files at the destination that were excluded from synchronization (`--exclude` or `--exclude-from`), regardless if these files would actually exist at the source or not.

**Which one shall I use?**

If you use merge files, you probably want to use `--delete-delay`, if available, otherwise `--delete-after`.

If you don't use merge files, you usually want to use
`--delete-during` which will be fastest.

Only if the storage space at the destination is very tight and the data to be synchronized just barely fits there, you may want to use `--delete-before` instead as in that case `--delete-during` could fail as the destination could run out of disk space yet `--delete-before` would then probably still succeed.

As for memory consumption, that's usually not an issue at all with modern systems which have plenty of spare memory available. It may be an issue with tiny embedded devices but those typically don't use `rsync` in the first place for file synchronization and also have very little spare disk space, too.

Comment: This is MUCH clearer and more detailed than the currently accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: I really wish —delete-excluded just “deleted excluded” instead of “delete excluded, and a regular delete as well”.

Answer (score 6):

One other point worth mentioning is that if your source directory ends with `/*`, then rsync will only consider *those* files and not the directory itself (and thus the absence of files that you want deleted on the destination).

If you're specifying a delete option above, but rsync looks like it isn't deleting, then check to make sure you're not accidentally globing and providing a list of files when you mean the directory itself.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. I was confused and couldn't understand why --delete-before didn't really seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on:

1. Who does the deleting
2. When it happens

Either the sender or the receiver can be instructed to do the deleting (I'm not sure why this matters). So when rsync from one computer connects to the rsync server on the other side, this determines who is effectively issuing the delete command.

When it happens is pretty easy... before means all the files are deleted, and THEN rsync copies over the files.  during means as it goes through the list of files, it deletes them when it comes to them, and after means it waits until all the files are transferred over and then deletes the remote side.  This matters only when the transfer gets interrupted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure none of these options are related to deleting things from the *sender's* side. All of them (AFAIK) relate to deleting things from the *receiver's* side. Also, you say: "before means all the files are deleted, and THEN rsync copies over the files" — is this right? I'd expect `--delete-before` to delete only those files that needed to be gone, not *all* the files! But I guess it's *possible* that rsync deletes everything and then transfers over the "new" (possibly unchanged) data...

Comment: Ah, "delete from sender's side" **is** supported by rsync, but the name of that option is `--remove-source-files`.